# webRTC/canvas support for older browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, streaming, webrtc, wowza, kurento

I have a personalized dynamic canvas that I mean to share with people, but I know the  tag it's not supported in older browsers (IE <9), so I've been thinking of a workaround. I'm planning on having a server browse the canvas instead of the person, and share a live-stream of the contents of the tab (the canvas) through webRTC.

I've successfully accomplished this part by making a Chrome extension and using google's [tabCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) to capture the tab content, and using Socket.IO on a nodeJS server to establish the webRTC session.

Now my problem lies in how to handle the stream on the remote side, because as I understand webRTC, webM and the  tag aren't supported in IE either.

I need help in figuring out how to convert the webM VP8 encoded livestream into something IE and older browsers can handle. maybe a flash fallback like FlashCanvas, a .swf converter, or a javascript video player like Video.JS4 but to be honest, I don't even know where to begin. I'm very confused with how to handle the livestream.

Am I over-complicating things?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :** I've been reading about using media servers such as [Kurento](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what_is_kurento.html) to re-publish the webRTC stream into, for example RTMP which is supported by flash, and using that a source for my player. The problem here is even thought Kurento is very well documented, I haven't been able to find examples similar to what I'm trying to do, and I'm still in doubt if it is capable of publishing an RTMP URL such as rtmp://localhost:port/mystream. People seem to be using a combination of Kurento with Wowza but I'm not grasping why.

**EDIT 2:** The reason people need to combine Kurento with Wowza it's because as of now, Kurento doesn't have an RTMP Endpoint, so even though you can ingest webRTC, you can only output RTP, so you then have to use that RTP Endpoint to process an SDP with Wowza's description, as explained [here](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-a-native-rtp-encoder-with-sdp-file).

Answer (score 0):

Flash plays VP6 codec (inside FLV container). VP8 is newer and goes into a WebM container. Flash does not play WebM files (no decoder source posted on the web).

Older browsers (IE versions below 9) should still be to handle JavaScript:
**Try**: https://github.com/dominikhlbg/vp8-webm-javascript-decoder. This needs a `.webm` file link.

Comment: Thanks @VC.One , would this work on a live-stream? I read somewhere that I need to first record the stream using some library like "RecordRTC" and then decode/feed it to an embed tag; And in the example you shared the .webm file is already recorded. But what I really need is to share the contents of a canvas/tab in real time.